# Remove year from title

Tags: customization

In several post titles I have "years" (eg: "Lorem ipsum - 2018"), it's not a problem. But in another part of the blog I call these titles in PHP:

`$shortitle = wp_html_excerpt( get_the_title(), 23, '...' );
<div class="col-md-9">' . $shortitle . '</div>`.

How could I remove the display of years in titles ? 
Thank you :)

Update:

Found the function str_replace, but it's weird for my case:

```
    $title_long = get_the_title();
    $excludeyears = array(" - 2017", " - 2018", " - 2019", " - 2020");
    $title_long_exclude_years = str_replace($excludeyears, "", $title_long);    

    $shortitle = wp_html_excerpt( $title_long_exclude_years, 23, '...' );
```

it displays:

> Lorem ipsum – 201...

Update 2:

Okay, it's a problem with "-" character, but I dont have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the problem is with the hyphen. WordPress converts hyphens with with spaces to en-dash. Following is the conversion with hyphens with WordPress:

> 1. Foo {3 hyphens, spaced} Bar → Foo — Bar (em-dash)
> 2. Foo{3 hyphens, no space}Bar → Foo—Bar (em-dash)
> 3. Foo {2 hyphens, spaced} Bar → Foo — Bar (em-dash)
> 4. Foo{2 hyphens, no space}Bar → Foo–Bar (en-dash)
> 5. Foo {1 hyphen, spaced} Bar → Foo – Bar (en-dash)

Refer [here](https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/how-wordpress-handles-dashes-and-hyphens/) for this.

For your specific issue, you can do the following. This has a limitation that date should be at the last of the title.

```
// WP converts hyphens with spaces to n-dash, so convert them to hyphen again.
$title = str_replace( array( '&nbsp;', '&#160;', '&ndash;', '&#8211;', '&mdash;', '&#8212;' ), '-', get_the_title() );
// Explode using hyphen;
$title =  explode( '-', $title );
// Remove last element i.e date.
array_pop( $title );
// Convert array to string.
$title = implode( $title );
// Echo.
echo $title;
```

OR
you can do the same using regex like the following which do not have the limitation as above:

```
        // WP converts hyphens with spaces to n-dash, so convert them to hyphen again.
        $title = str_replace( array( '&nbsp;', '&#160;', '&ndash;', '&#8211;', '&mdash;', '&#8212;' ), '-', get_the_title() );

        // Pattern for date with hyphen and space.
        $pattern = '(\s\W\s\d+)';

        // Replace with space.
        echo preg_replace( $pattern, ' ', $title );
```

Comment: Thank you for this long explanation. I understand better and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption that all the titles have same pattern, i.e hyphen followed by the year.

```
$title_long = get_the_title();
$title = explode('-' , $title_long);
$title = trim($title[0]);
$shortitle = wp_html_excerpt( $title, 23, '...' );
```

I guess this would do.